# Joining models in django through 2 ForeignKeys

Tags: python, django

Is there a possibility in Django to create a query that would uses two ForeignKeys to create a join between tables?

To illustrate what I mean suppose I have the following models in Django:

```py
class Author(models.Model):
     name = models.TextField()

class Publisher(models.Model):
     name = models.TextField()

class BooksSold(models.Model):
     author = ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books_sold')
     publisher = ForeignKey(Publisher, related_name='books_sold')
     books_sold = models.IntegerField()

class BooksPrinted(models.Model):
     author = ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books_printed')
     publisher = ForeignKey(Publisher, related_name='books_printed')
     books_printed = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to join the BooksSold and BooksPrinted tables using the Author and Publisher keys. In sql it would be:

```sql
SELECT A.author_id
      ,A.publisher_id
      ,A.books_sold
      ,B.books_printed 
FROM table_books_sold A INNER JOIN table_books_printed 
ON A.author_id = B.author_id AND 
   A.publisher_id = B.publisher_id
```

The method I am currently using is to iterate over one of the models join in through one of the `ForeignKey`s and filter with the other `ForeignKey`, which would be for this example:

```py
   def get_books_printed(books_sold_model):
       return next(b for b in books_sold_model.author.books_printed if b.publisher_id = books_sold_model.publisher_id

   books_sold_models = BooksSold.objects.all().prefetch(author__books_printed)
   for book_sold_model in books_sold_models:
       books_printed = get_books_printed(books_sold_model)
```

I would like to know if is there is a way to avoid iterating through all of the instances until I find the match with the other `ForeignKey`

Comment: I think model design can be more efficient. Can you please tell me in simple words what do you want as output? How much books has been printed of an author?

Comment: The models were made up just to illustrate the question. I am looking for a specific answer to the question and not just a work-around.